# IP address as the hostname for AppHarbor / App Engine urlfetch to cache DNS lookups

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dns, urllib2, appharbor

I have an AppHarbor app that I'm using as an external service which will get requested by my other servers which use Google App Engine (python). The appharbor app is basically getting pinged a lot to process some data that I send it.

Because I'll be constantly pinging the service, and time is important, is it possible to reference my appharbor app through its IP address and not the hostname? Basically I want to eliminate having to do DNS lookups and speed up the response.

I'm using Google App Engine's urlfetch (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview) to do the request. Is caching the ip address something urlfetch is already doing under the covers? If not, is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that DNS lookups will be your bottleneck, but anyway as far as I can see DNS lookups are cached by the system (for at least the TTL).

Answer (score 1):

You can theoretically send requests directly to an IP address, but you would have to also [pass the host header](http://drewish.com/content/2010/03/using_curl_and_the_host_header_to_bypass_a_load_balancer) so that the AppHarbor routing layer can figure out what application gets the request.

As Shay mentions, you shouldn't do this though - DNS queries are cached and are not likely to be a bottleneck and you're setting yourself up for breakage because the IP address might change with the domain being pointed to a new IP.

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for the AppEngine Sockets Trusted Tester ([here](https://docs.google.com/a/postmaster.io/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dF9QR3pnQ2pNa0dqalViSTZoenVkcHc6MQ#gid=0)) and use the normal python:

```
socket.gethostbyname(...)
```

Comment: I signed this doc over 8 months ago and still no answer from them.

Comment: That's kind of surprising, Amy is pretty responsive.  Maybe signup again or ask about it on the mailing list.